# Is it possible to open 2 activities with the first not being visible

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to open two activities with two startActivity one following the other, but in such way that only the second is visible appearing.

**The effect I need is when I'm on activity A go to activity C... but opening activity B**.

The stack would be A -> B -> C but the user would only see the C opening when pressing a button on A.

**I known that I could override onBackPressed on C so that it would open B...but I support version 1.6 so I can't override animations**.. and as such, activity B would appear as a new activity and not one on the stack already which is not the prefered behaviour.

Also, I'm not searching for a great "trick-shot" like putting the layout transparent or something like that.

Just want a YES and how, or NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I read points towards **not being possible**.

So I will settle for that.

Answer (score 0):

Define your B activity as following in manifest.

```
 <activity 
      android:name=".BrightnessActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
 </activity>
```

And also overide `onResume()` in activity B. In which call activty C by `startActivtiy(intent)`

Comment: This is not what i want as it will be seen flickering between activities.